# Hashids PHP and JS compatibility

Tags: javascript, php, hash, hashids

Hello I'm trying to use the Hashids library ([Website](http://hashids.org/javascript/)) in both of its versions, the PHP to generate server side hash and the JS to decode the given hash by the server. In both cases I'm using the same SALT.

PHP example:

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids(SALT);
echo $hashids->encode(9); //prints GX
```

JS example:

```
var hashids = new Hashids(SALT);
return hashids.encode(9); //prints rE
```

I know I'm not decoding the PHP version with the JS version as mentioned but, the idea is to illustrate that they both give different results using the same SALT and ID.

Does anyone knows if its even possible to use hashids the way I'm doing it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you using it at all, if the hash can be easily decoded on the clientside it's not even remotely secure, and you might as well just display whatever you want in plain text

Comment: Its because Im trying to display images that were saved using an encoded ID, security is not a problem in my case, no sensitive data is being displayed nor database iteration with the given ID, its just to find an image name

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking - are you saying that getting different results in PHP and JS implementations for the same input and salt is a bug? If so, you should probably report that on the github project rather than here.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using different library versions. Be sure that both PHP and JS are >1.0, and obviously print out the salt to be sure you're passing the right value.